# How to add validation check to multiple methods without boilerplate code?

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, conditional-statements, composition

There is the following code from [Android Basics with Compose](https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-compose/course?gclid=Cj0KCQjwusunBhCYARIsAFBsUP9laGxbRXuwO5dNZ9h-5RjR97VnMyoEfxrEjCzIm3iwL0Ei6xwPM-gaApJyEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) course by Google: https://pastebin.com/X0VZSmCg.

I need to implement checks in `SmartHome` class methods:

1. `turnOnTv()` and `turnOnLight()` methods should work only if `deviceStatus == "off"`.
2. All other methods should work only if `deviceStatus == "on"`.

How to achieve this purpose without conditions in every method?

Answer (score 0):

Great instinct to not add that logic duplicated to the 10-20 one line functions that do the operations.

Instead, all of those functions can be made private to the SmartHome class. Then define an enum type for the each action. Also have a class variable that keeps track of it the system is on or off. Define also a map that goes from each action enum to a Boolean meaning it needs to be on or off for this action.

Now you can make a single public function called takeSmarthomeAction that accepts an enum type for the action you want to take. It will lookup in the map if the system needs to be on or off. It will compare this with the variable of the smart homes current state. If it is not in the right state it can return early.

Finally if it proceededs you know it is the right state and you can use a switch case to call the corresponding actuion function from the given enum.

Hope that helps and is clear or I’ll type this up in code later!

Note: no need for inheritance, delegation or composition really, you can keep it very simple to start and do it all in the current class since you don’t want to expose those actions directly anyway just making them private is good. If wanted you can use delegation but since you’re trying to reduce boiler plate I wouldn’t bother.